# Как выбрать последние 10 записей через for?

Tags: php, for

У меня есть n-ое кол-во записей.
`$p_cnt = count($xmlstr->channel->item);`

я перебираю forom, как мне получить последние 10 записей, а не что бы все записи перебирались ?

```
for($i = max($p_cnt -10, 0); $i < $p_cnt; $i++) {
        echo($xmlstr->channel->item->title[$i])
        $news = [
        'title' => $xmlstr->channel->item->title[$i],
        'img' => $xmlstr->channel->item->image[$i],
        'url' => $xmlstr->channel->item->link[$i],
        'description' => strip_tags($xmlstr->channel->item->description[$i]),
        'data_public' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
    }
```

Всегда показывает одну и ту же запись 10 раз.
Но когда перебираю foreach 
То все нормально.

```
 foreach ($xmlstr->channel->item as $item){
        $news = [
        'title' => $item->title,
        'img' =>   $item->image,
        'url' =>   $item->link,
        'description' => strip_tags($item->description),
        'data_public' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];
    }
```

Что не правильно в цыкле for? 
Или как можно сделать тогда последних 10 записей foreach ?

Comment: Логично перебирать не с 0, а с `$p_cnt - 10`. Учтите только, что `$p_cnt` может быть меньше 10.

Comment: $xmlstr->channel->item[$i]->elemennt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$countItems = count($xmlstr->channel->item);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($xmlstr->channel->item as $key => $item){
            $i++;
            if($i > $countItems - 10){
                $news = [
                    'title' => $item->title,
                    'img' =>   $item->image,
                    'url' =>   $item->link,
                    'description' => strip_tags($item->description),
                    'data_public' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ];
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте array_slice: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php

```
array_slice($xmlstr->channel->item, -10);
```

Тест на массивах: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/441deb7d95229b7526504224546f02e1d95c0051

Answer (score 0):

Измените `$i` на `$p_cnt-10`. В итоге должно получится:

```
for($i = max($p_cnt-10, 0); $i < $p_cnt; $i++) {

}
```

Comment: Оно выберет первых 10 записей.

Comment: Последние же надо, не первые.

Comment: @Егор Банин, спасибо, поправил

Comment: Теперь что будет, если количество item < 10?

Comment: @ Егор Банин ,для этого я добавил max() =)

Comment: echo($xmlstr->channel->item->description[$i]); не чего не выводит вообще